# Change name of column password in Laravel 10 Auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I need change column password name from 'password' to 'user_password'. I don't know what is wrong in my code because after login nothing to do, redirect me to login form again.
Below my code:
User model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_firstname',
        'user_lastname',
        'user_email',
        'user_password',
    ];
    

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    

public function getAuthPassword() {
  return $this->user_password;
}

}
```

LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller {
   
use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
//    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    protected $redirectTo = 'admin';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username(): string {
        return 'user_email';
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required', 'user_password' => 'required',
        ]);
    }
    
    public function login(Request $request){

        $this->validateLogin($request);
        
          if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            if ($request->hasSession()) {
                $request->session()->put('auth.password_confirmed_at', time());
            }

            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}  


    protected function credentials(Request $request) {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'user_password');
    }

    public function showLoginForm() {
        return view('admin.login.login');
    }

}
```

CustomUserProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider as UserProviderContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;

class CustomUserProvider implements UserProviderContract {

    protected $model;
    protected $hasher;

    /**
     * The callback that may modify the user retrieval queries.
     *
     * @var (\Closure(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder):mixed)|null
     */
    protected $queryCallback;

    public function __construct(HasherContract $hasher, $model) {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials) {
        $credentials = array_filter(
                $credentials,
                fn($key) => !str_contains($key, 'user_password'),
                ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
        );

        if (empty($credentials)) {
            return;
        }

        // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
        // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
        // Eloquent User "model" that will be utilized by the Guard instances.
        $query = $this->newModelQuery();

        foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value) || $value instanceof Arrayable) {
                $query->whereIn($key, $value);
            } elseif ($value instanceof Closure) {
                $value($query);
            } else {
                $query->where($key, $value);
            }
        }

        return $query->first();
    }

    protected function newModelQuery($model = null) {
        $query = is_null($model) ? $this->createModel()->newQuery() : $model->newQuery();

        with($query, $this->queryCallback);

        return $query;
    }

    public function createModel() {
        $class = '\\' . ltrim($this->model, '\\');

        return new $class;
    }

    public function retrieveById($identifier) {
        
    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token) {
        
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token): void {
        
    }

    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials) {
        if (is_null($plain = $credentials['user_password'])) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }

}
```

config/Auth.php:

```
 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
```

Please tell me how can I login with changed columns names in User table.

Comment: It should be using the column you've added in `getAuthPassword`. It may be redirecting for another reason. Try adding some logging in your CustomUserProvider and check your logs in `storage/logs` for any hints as to what's going on.

Comment: May I ask why you want to change it? Usually deviating from framework patterns is a bad idea and would create code which is more difficult to maintain in the longer run.

Comment: Because I want connect old databases from several projects with laravel.

Comment: you don't need a custom user provider ... you just need to pass the password to the `attempt` call as the key `password` (this does not related directly to the name of the field on the table)

Comment: Yes! You were right! Only in atempt. I hed error because in user table was id_user after change to id everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override credentials() function in LoginController.php file.

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'user_email' => $request->input('user_email'),
            'password' => $request->input('user_password'),
        ];
    }
```